# Photon: rejoin room

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

i am new to photon. And my problem is, Whenever i reconnect and rejoin the game using reconnectandrejoin(), the playerlist.length is 0.

Lets say that there are 2 players A and B. And when A rejoins after disconnecting, its playerlist is 0 and masterclient is null.
Similarly, in B the playerlist count does not add up to be 2 and remains 1 as if the player A has not connected.

Eventhough, the reconnectAndRejoin returns true.

If there is a tutorial about rejoining can you please direct me towards it, or can you please show be how to rejoin a player properly.

Answer (score 0):

I answered on Photon's official public forums where this same question was asked, [here](https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/comment/51284/#Comment_51284).